# How to tell if number is natural?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm making a test, and there's a question: "Which one of the given expresions, takes value which is natural number".
$a) \frac{17}{21} + \frac{12}{42}$
$b) \frac{\sqrt{64}}{\sqrt{8}}$
$c) \frac{\sqrt{75}}{\sqrt{3}}$
$g) -\frac{11}{12}-\frac{1}{12}$

The answer is $c$ however I don't get how to figure this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to compute all given numbers.

For c):
$$\frac{\sqrt{75}}{\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{\frac{75}{3}}=\sqrt{25}=5$$

For d):
Is negative, hence not natural.

For a):
$\frac{17}{21}+\frac{12}{42}=\frac{34}{42}+\frac{12}{42}=\frac{46}{42}\in(1,2)$ hence not natural.

For b):
$\frac{\sqrt{64}}{\sqrt{8}}=\sqrt{\frac{64}{8}}=\sqrt{8}=2\sqrt{2}$ -- irrational.

Answer (score 3):

You have to simplify the expressions. For $(a)$,

$$\frac{17}{21}+\frac{12}{42}=\frac{17}{21}+\frac6{21}=\frac{23}{21}\;,$$

and since $\frac{23}{21}$ is not even an integer, it certainly isn’t a natural number.

For $(b)$,

$$\frac{\sqrt{64}}{\sqrt8}=\sqrt{\frac{64}8}=\sqrt8=2\sqrt2\;;$$

again this isn’t even an integer. In fact, this one isn’t even a rational number.

If you simplify $(c)$ similarly, you get $\sqrt{25}=5$, which is a natural number.

Finally, $-\frac{11}{12}-\frac1{12}=-\frac{12}{12}=-1$; this is an integer, but it’s a *negative* integer, so it’s not a natural number.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sqrt{75}}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{25\cdot 3}}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{25}\cdot \sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}= \sqrt{25}=5$$